# using gmail as smpt for deliver email from mvc controller

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, email

I'm trying to send email from asp.net mvc controller. Gmail account used here for smpt is configured to use with less security, so that's not the problem here.

> but I don't get any error message neither any exception, but it not
>   deliver at my expected email address.

I'm using code

```
var text = "email body to deliver";
SendEmail("mydeliverEmailAddress@gmail.com", text);

public static bool SendEmail(string SentTo, string Text)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "myGmailPass");
                client.Port = 465;
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.EnableSsl = true;

                try
                {
                    MailAddress 
                        maFrom = new MailAddress("sender_email@domain.tld", "Sender's Name", Encoding.UTF8),
                        maTo = new MailAddress(SentTo, "Recipient's Name", Encoding.UTF8);
                    MailMessage mmsg = new MailMessage(maFrom.Address, maTo.Address);
                    mmsg.Body = "<html><body><h1>Some HTML Text for Test as BODY</h1></body></html>";        
                    mmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mmsg.Subject = "Some Other Text as Subject";
                    mmsg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                    client.Send(mmsg);
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {    
            }
            return true;
}
```

Comment: Is it caught in the spam filter at the recipient?  There's really know way we're going to be able to troubleshoot this for you.

Comment: Also, why have you tagged your question with so many irrelevant tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait a minute. You are using your gmail account: `myemail@gmail.com` and trying to send an email on behalf of `sender_email@domain.tld`?

For more than obvious reasons that's never gonna work. So make sure that you are using the same email address as the one you are authenticating against:

```
maFrom = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Sender's Name", Encoding.UTF8),
```

You can only send emails from the account you are authenticated against. Of course the recipient email can be any address that gmail can deliver to.

You've got another issue with your code. You are using a wring port here:

```
client.Port = 465;
```

The correct port that gmail SMTP works with is the following:

```
client.Port = 587;
```

Also you might want to ensure that you have enabled less secure apps in your gmail account or you will not be able to use SmtpClient in .NET to send emails using this SMTP: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?pli=1

> but I don't get any error message neither any exception, but it not
>   deliver at my expected email address.

What error message do you expect to get when you did the worst ever possible thing? You wrapped your code in a try/catch block and in your `catch` block you did absolutely nothing. You just consumed the exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{    
}
```

So make sure that you do something useful with an exception if you are going to be catching it. For example something useful could be to log this exception and send an error message to the user saying that something bad happened and you couldn't send an email and that you are investigating the issue right now.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am updating it currently. It will be an answer shortly.

Comment: OK, now it is an answer.

Comment: Why don't you *start* with a complete answer?

Comment: I am typing the answer as I go. It's how I have always used this site. Providing bits by bits, raising the interest and incenting people like you to downvote :-)

Comment: Then don't hit "save" until it's done.  It seems to me you're just trying to be the [fastest gun in  the west](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/)

Comment: I am going to do whatever I want. I will be a gun if I want.

Comment: That's fine, I don't care.  Then you're going to continue to get down votes.

Comment: Sure, I am perfectly fine with that :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
     var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("YourSMTPServer", "SMTPServerPort"))
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("YourEmail",
                    "Password"),
            EnableSsl = false
        };


           string fromEmail = "YourEmail";
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
            mailMessage.To.Add("Recipient's EMail");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mailMessage.Body = "This is test Mail";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;



     smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```